# Example of a bounded space which is not totally bounded

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was trying to find an example of a bounded metric space which is not totally bounded. The only example I could come up whith was the natural numbers with the discrete metric.

However, like any other example with the discrete metric, I find this one artificial (not to say disappointing), so I was wondering if there is any non-trivial example of this.

(by non-trivial I mean not envolving the discrete metric or, if possible, envolving non discrete sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the open unit ball $B$ in an infinite dimensional Banach space. If $B$ is totally bounded so is its closure (exercise!). Hence $\textrm{cl}(B)$ is complete and totally bounded, thus compact. But this is false.

Answer (score 3):

Start with an arbitrary metric space (with metric $d$) that is not totally bounded, and take the new metric
$\overline{d}(x,y) = \min(1, d(x,y))$.